# How to address crumbling garage floor?

Tags: concrete, garage

I bought this house about a year ago and noticed these boards on the garage floor covering an area where the concrete is crumbled, it's in the corner of the garage. Based on the condition of the concrete and the walls around it I assume it is or was some sort of water issue. I'm not sure if the issue is still happening or if it was remedied but the floor was never repaired, I've yet to notice any water in this area.

My question is what can I do about this? Can I clean out all the loose concrete and pour new concrete into the open area to fill it and "smooth" out the floor a little bit? Or does anything in the pictures suggest the moisture problem still exists and I should address it?

Additionally is there anything further I should do to repair the walls?

[Pictures](https://imgur.com/a/zSkDwkh)

Comment: Get a nail/pointy thing and with hand, push into the wood.  If it goes in more than a 1/8 of a inch, the wood might need repair/replacement.

Comment: I'm not ready to condemn the concrete.  It looks like a bad mix and pour.  Maybe it was not mixed well and done by hand, or too long in the truck. I;m not an expert on concrete, but I think the issues are somewhat minor and the concrete is not actually crumbling as if to totally collapse and not be able to bear weight

Comment: Battery acid spill would be another possible cause, particularly in a garage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You certainly can "clean out all the loose concrete" to "fill it and smooth out the floor a little bit", but concrete will not be the correct product. Instead, look for a high strength, premium quality concrete resurfacing product made especially for this. Follow the preparation instructions for that product, which will certainly require thorough cleaning and may even require an acid wash.

I don't see any signs of an ongoing moisture issue that needs remedy; in fact, I think the damage could have been *chemical*, like what you would see where pool acid had been stored, or chlorine, or old automotive batteries...

Comment: OP might have to get the floor epoxied.